# Axios get request gets 401 error but then succeeds when I refresh the page

Tags: django, reactjs, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework, axios

When I "naturally" make an api call, e.g by clicking on "My Inventory" which makes a get request to api.mysite.com/api/inventory/uuid/, it fails with a 401 error. However, when I'm on that page and I refresh it, suddenly it all works (although my .catch method is still triggered, suggesting an error happened?!)
Here is my code:

```
    config = {
        headers:{
            'Authorization' : 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        }
    }
```

This is my axios get request:

```
        axios.get(this.url, this.config.headers)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    products: res.data
                })
                if (res.data.length > 0) {
                    if (!res.data[0].is_owner) {
                        this.setState({
                            inventory_owner: res.data[0].user_name,
                            is_owner: res.data[0].is_owner
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch(res => {
                console.log("error it didnt work "+res.response.data.detail)

            })
```

While I was writing this question, I noticed the 2nd call doesn't come from the refresh, but from `componentWillReceiveProps`, which as the following code (pretty much identical)

```
    componentWillReceiveProps() {
        const path = this.props.history.location.pathname
        if (path === '/inventory') {
            this.url = 'https://api.mysite.com/api/inventory/'
        }
        else {

            if(this.param1.length>12){
                this.param1 = this.param1
            }
            else{
            this.param1 = path[path.length - 1]
            }
            this.url = 'https://api.mysite.com/api/inventory/' + this.param1
        }
        axios.get(this.url, this.config)
            .then(res => {
                console.log("this work tho")
                console.log("the url "+this.url)
                console.log("the config "+this.config.headers.Authorization)
                this.setState({
                    products: res.data
                })
            })
    }
```

the console outputs identitcal values for url and config, so I'm not sure why 1 call fails but the other succeeds.

Comment: try to set config when you are requesting, or create a function for loading a config. it seems like when your page rendered the first time, it sets the config and won't change after authorization. so that authorization token wasn't passed on your first call. and when you refreshed the page, that config data has been set again with authorization and call succeeded.

Comment: Okay it works! (for now). I'm not sure why this is the case though since I had print statements before the axios.get calls and it printed out the correct values as opposed to null/undefined. Thank you!

Comment: Hey how did you fix this